# Serving Static d3.js and Html file through ngnx

Tags: macos, nginx

I wanted to serve static d3 and html file via nginx on a local browser.

I have got the nginx installed in conda env.

But I am not sure where to find the nginx.conf file and help it run the directory files on the browser.

Here is where nginx is installed:

```
/Users/user1/anaconda/envs/dl/bin/nginx
```

I use macOS.

Answer (score 1):

`nginx -V` will tell you the location of the configuration file. For example,

```
$ nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.15.8
built by clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2q  20 Nov 2018
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: ... --conf-path=/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf ...
```

Comment: Thanks. was able to find the conf file. I have confusion how to serve d3 and html files in a foler via nginx. I have written a conf code in conf file but it doesn't seem to serve it. How do I start the nginx service etc

Comment: I am getting this error after configuring the nginx file

nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /Users/user1/anaconda/envs/dl/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1